# Excel Losing Text Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a text box that is linked to a cell, however, when I change the link to another cell the formatting of the text box reverts to a basic font, there a way to prevent this from happening?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a text box is linked to a cell the text box takes on the formatting of that cell.  If you expect to be changing the cell reference you could do this:

1. Link the text box to some fixed cell, for example, `A1`.
2. Link that fixed cell to your percentage value cell, for example, `B10`.
3. When you want to change the text box, don't change the link in the text box.  Just change the link in the fixed cell that the text box is linked to.  In this example you would be changing the formula in cell `A1` so that it points to some cell other than `B10`.